# The rCharts scripts is not working in R Studio?

Tags: r, ggplot2, rstudio, scale, rcharts

Using `R studio` and the following the exact steps presented in [Rpubs](http://www.rpubs.com/dnchari/rcharts) which is a tutorial about `rCharts`, I successfully install all the require packages including:

```
library(rCharts)
library(plyr)
library(knitr)
library(reshape2)
library(scales)
options(RCHART_WIDTH = 600, RCHART_HEIGHT = 400)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(comment = NA, results = 'asis', tidy = F, message = F)
```

Then when I am just copy and paste the exact next script presented in [Rpubs](http://www.rpubs.com/dnchari/rcharts), as following:

Facetted Scatterplot

```
names(iris) = gsub("\\.", "", names(iris))
p1 = rPlot(SepalLength ~ SepalWidth | Species, data = iris, color = 'Species', type = 'point')
p1$print(include_assets=T)
```

I do not get the plot and instead in my console I get the following scripts:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src=C:/Users/Daniel/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/rCharts/libraries/polycharts/js/polychart2.standalone.js></script> 
 <style>
  .rChart {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto; 
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;
  }  
  </style>
<div id = 'chart28a83784220c' class = 'rChart polycharts'></div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var chartParams = {
 "dom": "chart28a83784220c",
"width":    600,
"height":    400,
"layers": [
 {
 "x": "Hair",
"y": "Freq",
"data": {
 "Hair": [ "Black", "Brown", "Red", "Blond", "Black", "Brown", "Red", "Blond", "Black", "Brown", "Red", "Blond", "Black", "Brown", "Red", "Blond", "Black", "Brown", "Red", "Blond", "Black", "Brown", "Red", "Blond", "Black", "Brown", "Red", "Blond", "Black", "Brown", "Red", "Blond" ],
"Eye": [ "Brown", "Brown", "Brown", "Brown", "Blue", "Blue", "Blue", "Blue", "Hazel", "Hazel", "Hazel", "Hazel", "Green", "Green", "Green", "Green", "Brown", "Brown", "Brown", "Brown", "Blue", "Blue", "Blue", "Blue", "Hazel", "Hazel", "Hazel", "Hazel", "Green", "Green", "Green", "Green" ],
"Sex": [ "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female", "Female" ],
"Freq": [     32,     53,     10,      3,     11,     50,     10,     30,     10,     25,      7,      5,      3,     15,      7,      8,     36,     66,     16,      4,      9,     34,      7,     64,      5,     29,      7,      5,      2,     14,      7,      8 ] 
},
"facet": null,
"color": "Eye",
"type": "bar" 
} 
],
"facet": {
 "var": "Eye",
"type": "wrap",
"rows":      2 
},
"guides": [],
"coord": [],
"id": "chart28a83784220c" 
}
    _.each(chartParams.layers, function(el){
        el.data = polyjs.data(el.data)
    })
    var graph_chart28a83784220c = polyjs.chart(chartParams);
</script>
```

Any Idea what is wrong and how I can fix it?

Comment: have your tried just p1?

Comment: @MLavoie Thnx it fixed the problem :)